# Laravel Best Practice: Print Json response

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I've been wondering what is the best way in Laravel to return a json array back to an ajax call. This is the way I'm working right now:

**Route in web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'users'], function () {
    Route::post('getOneTimeLink', [
        'as' => 'adminUserOneTimeLink', 
        'uses' => 'AdminUsersController@createOneTimeLink'
    ]);
});
```

**Controller in AdminUsersController.php**

```
public function createOneTimeLink(){
    $aResponse = [ 'someData' => 'someValue'];
    // do some stuff here

    echo json_encode($aResponse);
    die()
}
```

but I think there is another way to return the call instead of adding the json_encode then die() the execution... but I don't know it yet. I've tried to search but haven't yet found an answer. I hope any of you can help me.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return response()->json($aResponse);
```

More information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#json-responses

Answer (score 0):

Please try to embed this logic into your code:

```
$response = array( 'status' => 'success', 'message' => $Info );

return response() ->json($response)->withHeaders($this->headerArray);
```